# What is the relation between the Zynga platform and facebook games?

Tags: server, facebook

I decided to check the Zynga platform because I heard that Zynga can now host games and one is able to play these games using a Zynga account.

After registering for a game, I noticed that it opened directly and didn't ask me to create an account (as it is using my Zynga account).

The weird thing is the game's website sends you to its facebook page, where I have to log in using my facebook account to play.

How could a facebook game allow someone to play through the Zynga platform?

Answer (score 1):

The facebook [canvas game API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/canvas-games/) is simply an iframe loading external content.  It is perfectly conceivable that the same game software could function outside that iframe.

Any website can support using facebook's API and an authentication (log-in) mechanism.  It is only a slightly different API than the canvas.  There would need to be some extra work, but the port would be very straightforward.

Comment: does that mean that the game internally treats the users from facebook and zynga differently? meaning there will be more options for users from facebook to share things, but not available to zynga users?

Comment: That is entirely up to the game and its developers.  The specific implementation of connecting to facebook's services determine what is possible.  Only a game's developer knows exactly what they did and whether those features are available in both formats.